# how redirect domain from www.test.tk to https://test.tk

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

I am trying to connect a custom domain name with my website.
I deployed my website on **firebase** which gives me a domain name of *https://test.firebaseapp.com* and get a custom domain name *https://test.tk* from **freenom.com**.

I successfully connected my website with *https://test.tk* and its working fine.
But when i type *www.test.tk* its not working.

Please let me know how to redirect from *www.test.tk* to *http://test.tk* Or I have to get another custom domain name *www.test.tk* and redirect it to *http://test.tk*

Answer (score 1):

Connect the `www` version in Firebase Hosting and tell it to redirect to the non-www version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by adding CNAME record to the freenom(domain provider)